# The TTL is not changed in the ICMP packet

Tags: c, sockets

I use the `SOCK_RAW` to create the socket.

```c
if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)) < 0)
      {
            perror("Error");
            exit(1);
      }
```

I use the setsockopt to set the ttl in the packet, and then capture the packet through wireshark. However, the ttl in the packet is still 1. The getsockopt

```c
int ttl = 0;
while(ttl < MAX_TTL) // MAX_TTL is 56
      {
            memset(recv,0,BUFFER_SIZE);
            ttl++;
            if(setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, (char *)&ttl, sizeof(ttl)) < 0)
            {
                  perror("Error");
                  close(sockfd);
                  exit(1); 
            }
            if(sendto(sockfd, message, packet_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &remote_addr,addr_len) < 0)
            {
                  perror("Error");
                  close(sockfd);
                  exit(1);
            }
            if((ret = recvfrom(sockfd, recv, BUFFER_SIZE, 0,(struct sockaddr*) &remote_addr,(socklen_t *)&addr_len)) < 0)
            {
                  //perror("Error");
                  if(ret == EWOULDBLOCK || ret == EAGAIN)
                  {
                        printf("time out\n");
                  }
            }
            ICMP_packet_upack(recv, ret);
            sleep(3);
            //break;
}
```

The platform is macOS, and use clang to compile.

Comment: Please don't post images of text, copy-paste it as actual text into the question instead. And please add an explanation what the "text" means.

Comment: I am very sorry. I use ICMP protocol to implement the traceroute. but the ttl is not changed.

Comment: Why are you casting the ttl reference to a `char *`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Using `void *` for pointers is relatively new (only commonly used the last 20 or so years). Before that the "generic pointer type" used to be `char *`, and there might still be network programming books or tutorials around that uses those old pointer types. Then you needed to cast from any other pointer type.